# How to intercept a center-button press

Tags: android

I have an app in which it is essential that I execute some code when the user presses the centre button on an android device. I already process the user pressing the right hand button (the back button) via `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) / if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)` so I had assumed that pressing the centre button would be processed in a similar manner. But upon further investigation, it appears that onKeyDown is not called. So my question is; how to I intercept a centre-button press?

P.S. Much to my embarrassment, I'm not even sure what the centre button is called!

Comment: what is center button ? the one that gets you home ?

Comment: what does the center button do.! Is it the same as home button.!

Comment: the centre button on my phone takes you back to the "desktop".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't intercept** that key (if you are talking about the home-button)
It is an OS function, which takes the user to his launcher on short-press, and to the multitask-menu on long-press.

If is also a **[Core-app Quality Guideline](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/core.html)**.

> UX-N3 Pressing the Home button at any point navigates to the Home
>   screen of the device.

What you could detect is your application being sent to the background using [`onStop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29).

Before Android 3.0, activities could be killed directly from `onPause()` without hitting `onStop()`. So if you are targeting pre-honeycomb devices as well, you might need to look at the [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) event as well.

Comment: Will pressing that button always do an onStop()?, are you sure it won't sometimes just do an onPause() without onStop()?

Comment: Hitting the home-button will hide your activity completely, so it will call `onStop()`.

Comment: Since Android 3.0, `onStop()` is guaranteed to be called. But yes, if you are targeting older devices as well, you might need to switch to `onPause()` in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The center button you look for is most likely [`KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER). That one would often be in the center of phones. At least the older ones have it, but it's no longer a common thing. Also typically not present on tables.

That button has for most UI elements a default behavior of clicking the current thing. So try not to break that functionality (and return false from `onKey...`) for users that use dpad navigation in your app.